# Java XML Nodes length

Tags: java, xml

I am really confused with the XML DOM Tree structure.

For example I have this piece of XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Container>
    <Group>             
    </Group>
    <Group2>                
    </Group2>
</Container>
```

Shouldn't the Container node consists of only 2 children? Group and Group2?

```
File fXmlFile = new File("Test2.xml");
DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
Node firstNode = doc.getDocumentElement();
if (firstNode.getNodeName().toString().equals("Container")) {
    // Process container here
    Container container = new Container(); 
    System.out.println(firstNode.getChildNodes().getLength()); // why print out 5?

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because in between there is are nodes of type TEXT. They are implicit nodes.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Container>
    <!-- TEXT -->
    <Group>             
    </Group>
    <!-- TEXT -->
    <Group2>                
    </Group2>
    <!-- TEXT -->
</Container>
```

Your nodes Group and Group2 are of ELEMENT type. Mostly, following XML will give you count 2,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Container><Group></Group><Group2></Group2></Container>
```

Comment: Will anything go wrong if I omit those implicit nodes when iterating? I used a if condition to check getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE.

Comment: As per your xml, you do not need those TEXT nodes so it won't affect you. The check you added should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

You always have to be prepared to find text nodes -- in this case, containing nothing but whitespace -- anywhere in your document. Some parsers will discard whitespace; other parsers will preserve it, and create these nodes. You'll have to check the type of all your nodes.