# Wrong output while reading xml by java

Tags: java, xml

My xml file contains :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Contacts>
    <ContactGroup1>
        <person aa="sads">
            <name>Aghil</name>
            <emailid>aghilvarghese@gmail.com</emailid>
        </person>
    </ContactGroup1>  
</Contacts>
```

I am trying to read this by following java code :

```
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = (Document) dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
        doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();

        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());

        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName("ContactGroup1");
        Node nNode = nList.item(0);//take first cgroup
        NodeList nl = (nNode.getChildNodes());
        System.out.println("nodes in ContactGroup1 : " + nl.getLength());
        for (int i = 0; i &lt; nl.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node = nl.item(i);
            System.out.println("node type is " + node.getNodeType() + " " + node.getNodeName());
         }
```

The output is :

```
Root element :Contacts
nodes in ContactGroup1 : 3
node type is 3 #text
node type is 1 person
node type is 3 #text
```

But in ContactGroup1 there is only one node (ie person), isn't it?
Why this wrong output? What can I do to get it correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11623864/java-xml-nodes-length

Answer (score 0):

You can skip empty text nodes. Check this question: [How to remove #text from my Node parsing in Java dom xml parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650878/how-to-remove-text-from-my-node-parsing-in-java-dom-xml-parsing) 
So basically you should check it node is text and empty then skip it.